# gitignore for Unity VR project does not work

Tags: unity-game-engine, gitlab, version-control, gitignore

this is my first time posting so forgive me if I forget relevant information!

I am working with Unity on a VR project and I wanted to use some sort of version control, so I am using GitLab. To not push/pull around about 25k files worth of 5GB.

I got a .gitignore file recommended and also found it online myself: [gitignore template](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/Unity.gitignore)

If I use this gitignore file and clone or pull on another computer the "ignored"/shortened version, that Unity project will not run properly anymore, my guess is that it ignores too much for my case.

I have no idea of those kind of things and before I start commenting out one after one of all the ignored files, I wanted to ask here if someone had a similiar problem or might know what the issue could be in a more directed way!

I tried the above gitignore template and was expecting for it to work if I use it in my project and want to clone or pull the project on another PC.

Comment: "that Unity project will not run properly anymore" can you describe more about problem? what exactly happens? do you encounter compile error or runtime error? what's the error? .....

Comment: Your case is not special, and there is nothing in the linked `.gitignore` that belongs in source control. We know nothing about your project and how you committed the files to source control. Did you commit any files before you added the `.gitignore` file? Did you use LFS? Do you have a `.gitattributes` file that you committed to the repo? Be specific about the trouble you are having.